# Update to Parse ios SDK 1.8.5 errors

Tags: ios, parse-platform, swift2, facebook-sdk-4.0

I just recently updated to Xcode 7 as well as Swift 2 and quickly ran into errors when retrieving `PFFile`'s due to App Transport Security. So I updated to the most recent Parse SDK. I deleted from my project:

- `Bolts.framework`
- `Parse.framework`
- `ParseFacebookUtilsV4.framework`
- `ParseUI.framework`

and then dragged the same, updated, frameworks over into my project folder. Now, after cleaning and building, I am receiving errors within `PFFacebookUtils.h`: `Include of non-modular header inside framework module 'ParseFacebookUtilsV4.PFFacebookUtils'` on lines where there is declared:

```
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKAccessToken.h>

#import <FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginManager.h>
```

Has anyone ran into and solved this issue yet?

Also, I already have "Allow Non-Modular includes in framework modules" set to "Yes"

Answer (score 0):

`ParseFacebookUtilsV4` includes the `Parse` framework. Try deleting the `Parse` part. It could be causing build errors, it was messing my Parse project up.

Comment: I actually figured it out in my answer above, but thank you for your response!

Answer (score 0):

What did it for me was changing the original `#import <ParseFacebookUtilsV4/ParseFacebookUtils.h>` in my bridging header to:

```
#import <ParseFacebookUtilsV4/ParseFacebookUtilsV4.h>
```

Note the added "V4" at the end.